# Installed ubuntu on Win7 but no application found (no terminal, no browser ?)

Tags: windows-7

I have installed ubuntu yesterday on my Win7 laptop. Everything was all right. Really nice and easy installation. Congratulations to all you.

But I have a problem, I couldnt find any application even no terminal in the installation. And even not possible to install in system settings or software update menu.

Sorry for my ignorance but how can I download or install some applications ?
Thanks for your support.

Marsel

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu?  Which release?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 12.04, then applications can be downloaded and installed from the Software Centre (there should be a button for it in the Unity taskbar on your left).
As for upgrades, they should prompt you for it automatically, as and when updates come out.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Oh yes. After changing the display resolution the left bar became visible :)The first display resolution was too bad to be honest. So, may be this would be a feedback to the ubuntu developers. They could improve or precisely set the first start up display resolution. thanks guys. the rest is perfect.

Comment: To give valuable feedback to the developers, you should create a bug report on Launchpad: create a Launchpad account, login, then open a terminal and type `ubuntu-bug linux`, then complete the bug report.